# Realtime update from firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

My goal here is realtime update from firebase. I need to get comment from firebase and update it on this.note. Somewhere in function update() I did something wrong. Tutorial I [followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkaKLn_T1VM&list=PLB4AdipoHpxYPjGo0n2m6tmCLud_iSEbv&index=37).

```
methods: {
update(){
db.collection("form").onSnapshot((querySnapshot)=>{
    this.userdata1=[]
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
      this.userdata1.push(doc.data().comment);
    });
  });
},
editComment(userDetails) {
  $('#commentModal').modal('show'); 
  this.note = userDetails.comment || ''; 
  this.activeuser = userDetails.id; 
},
saveComment() {
  let id = this.activeuser;
  if (!id) {
    alert('Fail');
    return;
  }
  db.collection("form")
    .doc(this.activeuser)
    .update({
      comment: this.note
    })
    .then(() =>{
      this.update();
      $('#commentModal').modal('hide');
      console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
}
}
```

Entire code: https://pastebin.com/tx5F0zz8

Comment: You never do anything with `this.userdata1` after you fill the array.

Comment: As Michael noted, you get the data from Firebase, save it on "userdata1" and then don't use it, did you manage to look into this and check that the data is actually there on "userdata1"? (perhaps with a console.log).

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the watcher() function from the video at 4:38.